# how to wait for drop down population before executing protractor e2e tests?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I am testing a scenario where there are 3 checkboxes that are populated based on a service call and the response of http get.

The i am having is when i run the tests with `protractor conf.js` the drop downs have not yet been populated with the response from the http get response, and so when i try testing anything the browser stops and the tests fails.

Is there way so that protractor can wait before running tests on those drop downs to be filled?

```
conf.js:
// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
  //directConnect: true,

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  // Framework to use. Jasmine 2 is recommended.
  framework: 'jasmine2',

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['e2e/*.js'],

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4000/',


  // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};

test file:

var select = element(by.model('make'));
console.log(select);
select.$('[value="acura"]').click();
```

this fails on the click event because when this test runs the select has no option elements as the select gets populated from a json http get response.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the method below; before calling the click.

```
browser.waitForAngular();
```

Comment: accessing the select should be done through protractor,  using
`browser.driver.isElementPresent(elementToFind).then(function(isPresent){
                element(elementToFind).click
}`

Answer (score 0):

use `browser.wait()`-

```
browser.wait(function(){
     return elementPresent.isPresent();
     }).then(function(){
         element.click();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use protractor's inbuilt `wait()` method using `ExpectedConditions` that expects the drop down to be filled. Here's how -

```
var select = element(by.model('make'));
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(select.$('[value="acura"]')), 10000)
.then(function(){
    select.$('[value="acura"]').click();
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is what i get:        Message:
    Failed: Wait timed out after 10004ms - any idea

Comment: @jp310 can you update the html code for the drop down? Also how much time does the options take to populate?